# I can't play on the Frozen Shadows map

Tags: temple-run-2

I tried to play on the frozen shadows map on Temple Run 2 because a global challenge had come up on it, but every time I try to click on it, it starts loading but then the app closes completely and I go back to my phone's home screen. The only think I can think of doing next is uninstalling and reinstalling the game, but will I lose all of my progress so far?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 solutions that might solve your problem.

1. Close all other apps - Temple Run 2 might be crashing because of the lack of memory.

Or

2. Uninstall and Reinstall - some files might have gotten corrupted.

If you uninstall it however, while using iOS, chances are that you'll lose all your progress [even if you backup](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7607510?start=0&tstart=0). So I'd recommend against it. If you're using Android though, follow the steps described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o--XWegUxXo) to keep your save safe.